# Are questions about stock markets from a personal finance (as opposed to professional trading) on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have recently joined a trading platform and noticed that they had gained popularity after COVID-19 kicked in. Also, many of my work colleagues became interested in investing. So I assume there is a big interest in investing/trading among regular folks.

Since I and all persons that I know are primarily using this without professional trader training, I would see this as a way of managing personal finances.

I am wondering if general questions about the stock exchange mechanisms are on-topic here. This should clearly not include any specific stock.

Examples:

- how to interpret a value > x% for the Short Float
- how to interpret a value of y% for Institutional Owners when I want a long investment

Note: I am a newbie when it comes to investments, so it is hard to provide more precise examples.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Money.SE.
As is often the case, there's a fuzzy middle. Questions about investing in a specific stock are off topic. But if the question is really a general one, one for which avoiding the stock name still leaves a valid question, it may be fine.

Often, a question might start to be voted to close, but that minor edit is enough.

Explanation of short float, for instance, would be on topic, as it's of interest to an investor.